# AWS: Steps to pass a node.js application to EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, babeljs

I'm newbie with AWS and I'm developing a web application with node.js and react.js. My application works fine in my laptop but I want to upload it to AWS EC2.

When I simulate a production environment in my laptop, I have a /dist folder where are all the code of the front end and the server code is in  /src/server folder.

I have uploaded my app to EC2 and now I'm a little bit lost about the next steps.

First, I would like if there is any way to download the modules only if they are not installed
Second, I would like to know if its mandatory to use babel in this environment, because in all tutorial that I have followed to make the development these modules are always installed like a dev depencies. So, is it now mandatory to move all babel modules to dependencies? Right now, my script to this two steps is:

```
npm -i --production && cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node src/server/server.js
```

If I change babel-node for node then I've got an error with "import" command because I'm not using babel.

My scripts are:

[image]

Is there to make a build like I do for the front-end code but for the server code? How can I do it?

Fourt, the server who will be listening the calls to the api will be node server and this will get when I finish to make correctly my aws-start script. But ... Which is the best option to server the front-end pages?

Sorry, I've got too many questions because this is my first app in AWS.

**Edit I:**

Following the wise advices of @Corrie MacDonald when I build my code I've got this files and folders:

[image]

Next, I modify my *aws-start* script:

```
npm i --production && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/assets/js/bundle.js
```

But, I've got this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit II:**

My webpack.config.babel.js file is:

```
import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";

const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

console.log("devMode: " + devMode);


module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/client/index.js", //set entry file

    // Resolve to output directory and set file
    output: {
        path: path.resolve("dist/assets"),
        filename: "js/bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/assets"   //It's mandatory to define this publicPath to get access to the website when we reload pages
                                //or we access to them directly with url's which have directories of second level like 
                                //http://localhost:4000/directory-level-1/directory-level-2
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/client/index.html",    //where is our template
            filename: "../index.html",              //where we are going to put our index.html inside the output directory
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }            
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/bundle.css",
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }             
        })
    ],
    //It help us to detect errors. 
    devtool: "source-map", 
    // Set dev-server configuration
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './dist', 
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },

    // Add babel-loader to transpile js and jsx files
    module: { 
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[
                    { 
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        query: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/preset-react"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                use: [
                    devMode ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
                    "css-loader"],
                test: /\.css$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "saas-loader", 
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    publicPath: "/assets/images/",
                    outputPath: "./images/"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    publicPath: "/assets/fonts/",   //It's mandatory to get access to the fonts when we reload pages or access directly
                    outputPath: "./fonts/"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Edit III:

This are the folders of my development environment:

[image]

How you can see when I make a build I create the /dist folder with the front-end code, but my server code still being in /src/server folder. How can I create a /dist folder for my server code? Is that possible?

Comment: It looks like some dependency may not be resolvable in your bundle. What does document refer to? Sometimes in bundled project, you need to add extra configuration (in this case, within your webpack config) to specify third party and external dependencies that shouldn't be bundled in the default way.)

Comment: I have updated my original post with my webpack.config.babel.js file.

Comment: `dist/assets/js/bundle.js` looks like client code, it is meant to be loaded by the browser. You should not try to run it on the server.

Comment: Ok, so, where is my server code? If I'm not wrong, when I make a build, I only do it about my client code. So, how can I make a build for the server code? Or this is not possible?

Comment: You mentioned that you have a Node API. The Node API should be run on your server, and your bundled front-end should be hosted on a webserver. As I mentioned in my answer, I would recommend you do this as a static AWS S3 website, while hosting your node API within your EC2 instance. You can also serve your bundle from the EC2, but it will likely require further configuration (Unless you get a pre-set AMI)

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! I understand that I've got my code in two parts, one is front-end and is inside the /dist folder after make a build and then my server code, where originally is in /src/server folder how you can see in this post. But the first problem that I have found is when I try to run my server node, because he requires babel modules. But in production Babel modules must not be required because previously I have made a build of my server code. And this is what I think I'm not doing and I don't know how is do it. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into a lot of detail about automated building procedures, the steps usually go as follows:

- Build Code
  -- Here, your source code is built and transpiled into a distributable format, which usually goes into a `dist/` folder.
- Upload your distributable code.
  -- Here, all of the files you have built should be uploaded (manually or automatically) to your EC2 instance.
- Run a startup script
  -- Here, any project startup code should be run in order to actually start your server.

You don't need babel in production because your project should already have been built by that point. However, if you are building on the EC2 instance, instead of just uploading your dist, then you will need it.

In order to turn your EC2 into a routable, reachable web server, you will need to configure some security and routing policies on AWS. You will need to ensure that the instance has a routable IP (or you can use the automatically generated DNS provided by AWS). Secondly, you'll need to ensure that your security policy allows port 80 (at the very least, and any additional ports you need to interact with the server - for HTTPS, SSH or something else.)

Once you have all this in place, you should be good.

**EDIT**

If you want to serve static HTML pages, you will have to ensure that you have set up your EC2 container as a web server with something like Apache. However, I would recommend that you run your Node Server exclusively from the server and host your static webpack bundle on S3 as a static website.

**EDIT 2**

- Here's an introduction to setting up your EC2 instance for node. - https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c
- Here's an introduction to setting up a static website with S3. - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: Hi @Corrie MacDonald!!! Thank you very much for your appreciated help!!! I have updated my original post with an error :S

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you for the links!!!! But I'm getting the same problem. How can I run my server code :)